# Show that $End_A(A)$ = {$r_a$ | $a ∈ A$}

Tags: representation-theory, modules, algebras

Let $k$ be a ﬁeld and let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Denote by $End_A(A)$ the set of all $A$-homomorphisms
of the regular $A$-module $A$ into itself. Fix $a ∈ A$, and deﬁne the $A$-module homomorphism $r_a :
A → A$ by $r_a(x) = x*a$.

$\\$
Show that $End_A(A)$ = {$r_a$ | $a ∈ A$}

$\\$
Answer:
$\\$
Obviously I can see that, for any $a$ we have $r_a$ is in $End_A(A)$, but how do I go about the other direction? Namely why is it that any endomorphism at all has this very simple form? I just don't see it...

Comment: Let $f$ be an $A$-endomorphism of $A$ and let $x \in A$. Consider the fact that $f(x)=f(x \cdot 1_A)=xf(1_A)$. So, how does this fit into the scheme of right multiplication?

Answer (score 2):

If $f\in\operatorname{End}_A(A)$ then by definition $f(ax)=af(x)$ for all $a\in A$ (and $f$ is also additive). Now let $b=f(1)$, then for all $a\in A$ one has $f(a)=f(a1)=af(1)=ab=r_b(a)$, so $f=r_b$, identically.